# struggling to order by title

Tags: order, title

i have the following page https://gundog.world/my-favorites/  (to view,user=stack pass=exchange)
the page functions correctly but i am trying to put the generated list into ascending order by post title. i have tried numerous $args but not seem to be correct. can any one see any obvious errors? please be kind this is only a hobby. many thanks in advance

the list generated are post types ,i am usinng the titles of the posts plus a few fields.

```
<?php
    // If this file is called directly, abort.
    if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
        die;
    }

$args = array( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order'   => 'ASC', );
$object_id          = $item->object_id ;
$object_type        = $item->object_type;
$field = get_field('label', $object_id);
  $value = $field['value'];
  $label = $field['label'];
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();


echo '<li class="cbxwpbookmark-mylist-item '.$sub_item_class.'" style="text-align: center !important; list-style:none !important;">';

?>

<div style="background: #dff0d8; border-radius: 5px; border:black 3px solid;padding: 15px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <h2 class="club_title"><div style="padding-top: 15px;"><?php    do_action( 'cbxwpbookmark_bookmarkpost_single_item_start',$args,$object_id, $item );
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $object_id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $object_id ) . '</a>' . $action_html;
            do_action( 'cbxwpbookmark_bookmarkpost_single_item_end', $object_id, $item );?></div></h2>
        <?php   $field = get_field_object('subs_due_for_renewal_on', $object_id);
         echo '<div class="due_on">'.$field['label']; ?><?php echo $field['value'].'</div>'; ?>
<?php
    $buttons = array(
        'subs_paid' => 'Subs Paid: ',
        'sched_rec' => 'Schedule Received: ',
        'tri_ent' => 'Trials Entred: '
    );
    foreach($buttons as $key => $val){
        $m_val = ucfirst(get_user_meta( $user_id, $key.'_'.$object_id, true ));
        $a_class = '';
        if( empty( $m_val ) ){
            $m_val = 'No';
        }
        else if($m_val == 'Yes'){
            $a_class = 'is_active';
        }
        echo '<button class="button button_toggle '.$a_class.'" data-user_id="'.$user_id.'" data-meta_key="'.$key.'_'.$object_id.'" data-meta_value="'.$m_val.'"><span>'.$val.' <span class="status">'.$m_val.'</span></span></button>';
    }
    echo '<button class="button clear_line" data-user_id="'.$user_id.'" data-option_id="'.$object_id.'">Clear Selections</button>';
?>
 </div>
<?php
echo    '</li>';

*emphasized text*
```

Comment: You define `$args` but then you never use it (at least not in the code snippet you've posted). Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/403311/edit) to show us how you're getting the items in your list (are they posts? pages?).

Comment: edited , thankyou

Comment: I, for one, am still not seeing `$args` being used anywhere. Regardless, if you're using `'orderby' => array( '$object_id' => 'ASC' )` in a wp query, what is that? If you want to just order by title you should be using `$args = array( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order'   => 'ASC', );`. (Incidentally, you'd never surround a var with single quotes like `'$object_id'`, as the var simply won't be interpreted.)

Comment: thankyou i corrected that bit, how to use the $args is what im struggling with , just a starting point so i can learn a little more ,thank you for the correction.